# Main Navigation 3 (Drawer and Stack) together problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react navigation version 3
I trying to use Drawer and Stack together
I am implementing a navigation drawer and works well 
But when I use stack navigation I can't see the back button option in the header
Drawer -> ListScreen ->onpress item open stack navigation to view profile ->
here I can't go back to ListScreen
I tried edit navigation option and add custom properties but still, I don't understand why it's not visible

const AuthStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  HomeStack: {
   screen.
    screen: LeadScreen,

```
headerBackTitleVisible:true,

navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({

  headerLeft: <Icon     
  name='arrow-back' onPress={ () => { navigation.goBack() }} style={{width:100}} />

  ,
  title: `${navigation.state.params.name}'s Profile'`,
    headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
  },
  headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, textAlign: 'center'},
}),
```

},

});

//navigate('Profile', { name: 'Brent' })

const AppStackNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  'בית':HomeScreen,
  'רשימת לידים':LeadsScreen,
  'ניהול סוכנים':ManageUsersScreen
  ,
  'הגדרות':SettingsScreen
},{
  contentComponent:CustomerDrawerComponent
}

)

const MainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  HomeDrawer: AppStackNavigator,
  AuthStack: AuthStackNavigation, // You will use this.props.navigation.replace('HomeDrawer') after login process.
})

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigation);

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you

Comment: I edited the post